Mouse cut and paste terminal issue - Wierd characters at end of paste sometimes
I'm experiencing a wierd issue with Ubuntu 22.04.
Sometimes, when I cut and paste into a terminal I get odd characters after the pasted text.
Please note. this is not the enable-bracketed-paste issue as I have that already turned off.
It seems to do it in xterm, uxterm and gnome-terminal. It's making cut-and-paste almost unusable.
I've changed my mouse, plugged it into a different USB port, etc but the problem still persists.
Sometimes I get the last few characters of the pasted text repeated and sometimes they're just random characters.
I've reinstalled ubuntu and the problem still occurs.
Can anyone help please.

a screenshot with an example of the issue might be useful... [edit] your question accordingly.

Please edit your question and title to clarify this issue specifically happens when pasting on the prompt of a terminal.
